# Trying to create a function for a button to display two text box answers when the user input is multiplied

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim result As Decimal
    result = Calc(txtGrams.Text) & Calcul(txtTroyOunces.Text)
    MessageBox.Show(result)

End Sub

Private Function Calc(ByVal a As Decimal) As Decimal
    ' declare variables and convert to decimal
    Dim Grams As Decimal
    a = txtGrams.Text
    Grams = a * 31.1035

    ' determine if text boxes txtGrams and txtTroyOunces is empty
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(a) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
    Else
        Return Calc(Grams)

    End If

#Disable Warning BC42353 ' Function doesn't return a value on all code paths
End Function
#Enable Warning BC42353 ' Function doesn't return a value on all code paths

Private Function Calcul(ByVal b As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim Ounces As Decimal
    b = txtTroyOunces.Text
    Ounces = b * 0.911458
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(b) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
    Else
        Return (Ounces)
    End If
#Disable Warning BC42353 ' Function doesn't return a value on all code paths
End Function
#Enable Warning BC42353 ' Function doesn't return a value on all code paths
```

When I click my convert button I get this error:

> $exception    {"Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."}   System.StackOverflowException

Comment: `Return Calc(Grams)` is inside `Calc()` so calls `Calc()` again ad infinitum.  Perhaps you just want `Return Grams` ?  You are also checking the validity of the arguments *after* you use them and it's best to fix those warnings rather than suppressing them.

Comment: Instead of disabling the warnings why not just return 0 on failure? That's what will be returned anyway if _you_ don't return anything. But by doing it yourself you'll at least no longer have that warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Incidentally, if you're trying to convert troy grams to troy ounces, your conversion factor should be 0.0321507 not 0.911458, but if it's ounces to troy - all good.

Firstly, you shouldn't disable option strict. It makes coding a little harder, but unless your code really needs it disabled, leave it on. It forces you to write better code.

Secondly, your error on your line ..

```
result = Calc(txtGrams.Text) & Calcul(txtTroyOunces.Text)
```

While it looks kind of OK, you have a problem that `result` is declared as a Decimal type, and you probably meant to declare it as a String type - When using string types, the `&` operator will join two strings together. Fair enough, but in Vb, if you're trying to assign a value to a Decimal type, `&` does something completely different - it tries to do a logical AND operation on the bitwise values. This is why it is so important to have `Option Strict` on. This error would have been picked up by the IDE before you had got any further in your code writing.

If you did simply change the declaration of `result` to a String type, the `&` operator, will join your numbers with no spaces, hence the changed `MessageBox.Show` line

Thirdly, do your validation of the TextBoxes in the button click event to make sure that the values entered are valid decimals. Like this..

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Btnconvert.Click
    If IsNumeric(TxtGrams.Text) And IsNumeric(TxtTroyOunces.Text) Then
        Dim grams As Decimal = CDec(Val(TxtGrams.Text))
        Dim troyOunces As Decimal = CDec(Val(TxtTroyOunces.Text))
        Dim convertedToTroy As Decimal = Calc(grams)
        Dim convertedToGrams As Decimal = Calcul(troyOunces)
        MessageBox.Show(convertedToGrams & "g   " & convertedToTroy & "Troy oz")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Enter numbers > 0")
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see there is extra code that gets a numeric value from the TextBoxes ( using `Val`) and also there I'm using  `CDec` to convert the numbers to decimals. It looks long winded at the moment, but you'll get used to it.

Also, another coding tip - When you are choosing names for subs and functions, pick a name related to what it does - If you come back to some code six months later, at least you'll have an idea of what it does. It's not so important in the current code as the subs etc are short and it's obvious what they do, but get into the habit anyway. It's a good one to cultivate.

In your original conversion functions, you have the following lines..

```
a = txtGrams.Text
```

and

```
b = txtTroyOunces.Text
```

these are redundant because when you call the function from your BtnConvert_click handler, the value is already passed to `a` and `b` .. you don't need to get it again from the TextBox

Now that your validation is done in the button click, the two calculation functions look much cleaner and you don't need to muck around disabling compiler warnings. Have a look below.

```
Private Function ConvertToGrams(ByVal a As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim Grams As Decimal
    Grams = a * 31.1035D
    Return Grams
End Function

Private Function ConvertToTroy(ByVal b As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim Ounces As Decimal
    Ounces = b * 0.911458D
    Return (Ounces)
End Function
```

In the two functions above, you'll notice that there is a letter `D` after each conversion factor. This simply makes sure that the compiler treats the numbers as Decimal types. Another good practice when dealing with literal numbers.

Hope this helps.

If an answer sorts out your problem, don't forget to click the tick next to the answer - It makes sure that the user gets reputation points and makes it easier for anyone else who has the same problem to see that your question has an accepted answer that might work for them as well. (And the person answering the question gets reputation points btw)